# Compare \ Create and copy files from 2 locations to a 3rd with powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a Citrix 6.5 farm and a VDI horizon view 6 environment each with their own separate profile locations.
  I have set up a Horizon view 7 environment now and would like to compare the desktop and favorites folder from citrix and HV6 and then create a new central location in a folder and copy the most recent files from the comparison to the central location...  I am still rather new to power shell so I will list what i have so far When I run it it acts like it's running but does nothing.  I need some help.     `#Current Citrix user folder profile names
    $name = Get-ChildItem "\usolt-isln.smcusa.com\ctxprofiles\" -Directory -Recurse

```
#Citrix profile location
$Folder1Path = "\\usolt- 
isln.smcusa.com\ctxprofiles\$name\UPM_Profile\Desktop"
#HV6 profile location
$Folder2Path = "\\usind-vdifs-01\ViewProfiles\$name.V2\Desktop"
#HV7 Location
$Folder3Path = "\\USIND-corpfs-01\Users\$name\vPCDocuments\Desktop"

#Creates final destination path if it doesn't exist
$path = "$Folder3path"
If(!(test-path $path))
{
      New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $path
}


$Folder1Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder1Path
$Folder2Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder2Path

$FileDiffs = Compare-Object -Reference Object $Folder1Files -Difference 
Object $Folder2Files

$FileDiffs | foreach { 
     $copyParams = @{
       'Path' = $_.InputObject.fullname
       }
       if ($_.sideIndicator -eq "<=")
       {
           $CopyParams.Destination = $Folder2Path 
        }
        else
       {   $CopyParams.Destination = $Folder1Path 
       }
       Copy-Item @CopyParams -Force


   $copyParams2 = @{
       'Path' = $_.InputObject.fullname
       }
       if ($_.sideIndicator -eq "<=")
       {
           $CopyParams2.Destination = $Folder3Path
        }
        else
       {   $CopyParams2.Destination = $Folder2Path
       }
       Copy-Item @CopyParams2
       }`
```

Comment: Instead of rolling your own copy code, it would be much simpler (and more robust, and more efficient) to use `robocopy` and copy first the newer files from the one source to the destination and then the newer files from the other source to the destination. Two lines of code, done.

Comment: Can Robocopy compare the two so as not to overwrite anything of the same name but leave just the newest version

Comment: Yes. Robocopy has an option to copy newer files only. When you do that two times in a row, the newest files will be in the destination. I'd recommend to use robocopy for every copy job, even in Powershell. It's *orders of magnitude* better than anything Powershell has to offer.

Comment: Can robocopy recurse through the 342 different folder names ( Users) with an Out-file from PS?  Sorry I'm new to all this scripting ( esp PS)

Comment: Would this be the correct way to write it $name = Get-ChildItem "\\usolt-isln.smcusa.com\ctxprofiles\" -Directory -Recurse

ROBOCOPY “\\usolt-isln.smcusa.com\ctxprofiles\$name\UPM_Profile\Desktop” “\\usind-vdifs-01\ViewProfiles\$name.V2\Desktop” /e /l /ns /njs /njh /ndl /fp /log:reconcile.txt

Comment: You can iterate the 342 usernames from your file in a Powershell loop and call robocopy inside that loop. Not a problem at all.

Comment: I have a file that contains all the folder(profile) names called profile.txt but I was thinking that the get-child item would be doing the same as thats where the out-file of names came from

Comment: Or if you want to copy the *entire* "profiles" tree from both sources, you don't need a loop at all and simply let robocopy do the whole thing. If you only want to copy specific users, you can also work with the include/exclude options robocopy offers.

Comment: I mean, nothing bad can happen. Read the commandline options of robocopy, pick the most interesting-sounding ones, try it a few times with a single user profile (so it doesn't take forever to retry), look at the results, experiment a bit and when you're happy, modify the command so it runs over the whole tree. There are a lot of areas where Powershell shines, but copy jobs isn't one of them.